# Error Handler Servlet: how to get exception cause

Tags: java, servlets, exception

I have an error servlet configured in my web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/ExceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

right?

In my (generically) servlet:

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        ...
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("some mesage", e);
    }
}
```

so, "e" will be the root cause in this case.

In my ExceptionHandler class, I have:

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
    throwable.getCause() //NULL
}
```

this is the problem. throwable.getCause() is null.

Comment: are you sure that this is the same exception and you are not mixing things up? BTW, your "generic servlet" code has a typo in exception handling code and does not compile.

Comment: Maybe instead of new ServletException("some message", e) you have new ServletException("some message" + e)? Would make sense to inspect the supplied Throwable object carefully, to see maybe you have a bug somewhere in your code. ;-)

Comment: I wrote the "generic servlet" now. please ignore syntax errors.

Comment: I can't use new ServletException("some message" + e) unless e.toString() gives me all the stack trace. That's what I want. The original line of the error.

Comment: never mind my comments, I just added an answer :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the exception caught by the servletcontainer is a `ServletException` and the `<error-page>` is declared to catch an exception *other* than `ServletException`, then its cause will actually be unwrapped and stored as `"javax.servlet.error.exception"`. So you basically already have it as `throwable` variable and you don't need to call `getCause()` on it.

See also 5th paragraph of chapter 9.9.2 of [Servlet 2.5 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index.html):

> If no `error-page` declaration containing an `exception-type` fits using the
>   class-hierarchy match, and the exception thrown is a `ServletException` or
>   subclass thereof, **the container extracts the wrapped exception**, as defined by the
>   `ServletException.getRootCause` method. A second pass is made over the error
>   page declarations, again attempting the match against the error page declarations,
>   but using the wrapped exception instead.

By the way, it's better to use the [`RequestDispatcher#ERROR_EXCEPTION`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#ERROR_EXCEPTION) constant instead of hardcoding it.

```
Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: I know. thanks. it's an old system that I'm kinda hard fixing. The problem is that the top of the stack trace is the line " throw new..." in the servlet, and not the real cause of the exception. The real cause is inside the block try {}, right? right. :)

Comment: Servlets are by contract required to wrap any catched exceptions in a `ServletException` so that you can utilize servletcontainer's facilities to handle it further. The original exception will be unwrapped and treated further as is.

Comment: I guess my servlet implementation (2.4) with java 5 does not have this constant.

Comment: Maybe you've imported the wrong interface? It should be the `javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher` one (click the link in answer to see javadoc). You may accidently have autocompleted the wrong one in your IDE. Jersey (JAX-RS) for example also has such an interface.

Comment: If you are using Servlet API 2.4 then I would recommend you to update your code as per my suggestion (see my answer) and see if it makes the problem go away.

Comment: @Neeme: It's already solved :) The OP only cannot seem to locate the constant.

Comment: I'm not convinced that it is solved, he still seems to be struggling to see "the real cause of the exception". :-P

Comment: Maybe your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is cluttered with outdated servletcontainer-specific libraries like `servlet-api.jar`. Get rid of them.

Comment: @user468508 What servlet container (+version) are you actually running this on? And Java version?

Comment: it seems that other people are also confused about this automatic un-wrapping (http://alicia.orconhosting.net.nz/computer/scwcd/SCWCDNotesSec4.html), so this might be container-specific. Better write in a check for ServletException, just in case.

Comment: @Neeme: that would have been a bug in the servletcontainer since that's just clearly specified in error handling sections of the Servlet API specification (in case of version 2.5, see chapter 9.9.2, 5th paragraph). I have however never seen such a container yet.

Comment: @BalusC: right. this is an old software that indeed has servlet-api.jar in the /WEB-INF/lib, although the servlet container is: apache tomcat 6.0.26.0 with java 6

Comment: i'm sorry, but RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION will just replace "javax.servlet.error.exception"?

Comment: Tomcat 6 is a Servlet 2.5 container (`web.xml` should by the way preferably be modified to match Servlet 2.5 spec). And yes, `RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION` should be preferred over hardcoding its value. It's a constant provided by the API. You can of course also keep hardcoding, it will work, but that's just a poor practice.

Comment: @BalusC: I couldn't agree more that RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION should be preferred over hardcoding its value. I just point that this might not solve the problem. But I guess removing the libs maybe do so.

Comment: I have never said that it should solve the problem as mentioned in your question. It's just a "by the way". The answer to your problem is that you don't need to call `getCause()`. You already have it as `throwable`. Reread the textual content of my answer. Don't focus on code snippets only.

Comment: I'm not looking at code snippets, nor even textual context. I'm looking far above :) i'll perform the changes and report if it works.

Comment: @BalusC: ok I removed servlet-api.jar from project's WEB-INF/lib and still the same: java.lang.Exception cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletException. I also modified web.xml to "catch" only ServletExceptions but still the same. But I guess the problem may be another issue here. Guess my core question has already been answered. thanks.

Comment: Once again, you do not need to cast it. You do not need to call getCause(). You already have the original exception. It's the `e` which you caught in the catch block of the servlet code. Just work on the `Throwable` which you obtained as request attribute. That's it.

Comment: As far as I see, at least some servlet containers would always unpack ServletExceptions (and descendants), even if exception-type is set to ServletExceptions.

Answer (score -2):

EDITED.

Ok, this might be wrong, I do not have personal experience with error handling servlets: *Instead of [getCause()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29), add an `instanceof` check for [ServletException](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletException.html), if it passes, cast your Throwable to [ServletException](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletException.html) and use [getRootCause()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletException.html#getRootCause%28%29).* (BalusC seems to have a better solution, for newer Servlet API versions)

See [Exceptions Without Root Cause](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2005/11/exceptions-without-root-cause) for in-depth discussion.

Newer Servlet API versions do not have this issue, but **if you are using some old version ([2.4](http://www.jdocs.com/servlet/2.4/javax/servlet/ServletException.html) or older)** you should also update your ServletException throwing code:

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        ...
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ServletException se = new ServletException(e.getMessage(), e);
        se.initCause(e);
        throw se;
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.Exception cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletException. maybe if I change web.xml in exception-type ?

Comment: @user: It's indeed not a `ServletException` at all. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yep, better follow BalusC suggestion, I also updated my answer.

Comment: @Neeme: your updated code makes also no sense at all. It already sets the cause internally. Also, the `getRootCause()` just delegates to the `getCause()`. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Depends on the version of Servlet API, did you see the page I linked to? It is outdated (2005) but you cannot make too many assumptions about the Servlet API version, so I guess my answer still has some value for legacy Servlet API users.

Comment: Could be, but OP isn't using Servlet 2.2 or older.

Comment: Also 2.4 has this issue: http://www.jdocs.com/servlet/2.4/javax/servlet/ServletException.html

Comment: How so? This issue is caused by running webserver on top of Java SE 1.3 or older. Plus, the linked page treats a completely different problem. The request attribute contains the root cause of the exception. Period. The servletcontainer is smart enough to grab it by `getRootCause()` before setting as request attribute.

Comment: As long as we do not know the exact servlet container (+ version) and java version, nothing is certain. This seems to be somewhat gray area and can vary between containers.