# How to bubble up exceptions in Java ee?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, error-handling

In a Java EE project I have services that can throw errors such as `throw new PersistenceException("My message here");` how do I get these error messages to display in a JSP view? I would think this is something simple to look up and figure out but I've had no success.

Answer (score 2):

There the `<error-page>` declarations in `web.xml` are for. E.g.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.persistence.PersistenceException<exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/db.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Be however careful with declaring overly generic exception type (`ServletException` or superclass) as "generic" error page, it would likely take over all exceptions. Use `<error-code>500</error-code>` instead.

#### See also:

- [Error Handler Servlet: how to get exception cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207586/error-handler-servlet-how-to-get-exception-cause/4207997#4207997)
- [How does server prioritize which type of web.xml error page to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299169/how-does-tomcat-prioritize-which-type-of-error-page-to-use/5299474#5299474)

Note that I assume that those exceptions represent unrecoverable situations (i.e. there's no means of an user error which the enduser should fix by e.g. re-entering the input in proper format — just a simple validation error).

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception in the controller, put it (or its message) in a request attribute, and let the JSP get it from the request and display it, as it would with any other object.