# Redirect to an ember page when exception occurs in my filter

Tags: servlets, ember.js, filter, exception

My application has a filter that throws a user defined exception.
So, whenever that user defined exception occurs, i want my application to redirect to an ember page.
Something like,
if( evil )
{ throw myexception("exceptioncode") 
}

=>> Redirect user to an ember page

I just need the steps that I need to carry out in order to perform the above function.

Comment: what have you tried? what do you mean by `filter`? please show your code.

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://blog.gennady.pp.ua/how-to-handle-backend-errors-in-ember-js-properly/)

Answer (score 1):

When filters or any other services from backend sends an exception, they are considered as `AdapterError` in ember.

So you need to check them and redirect to proper route :

```
//routes/application.js
actions: {
    error(reason){        
      if(reason.isAdapterError === true){
        this.transitionTo('exceptions');
      }
    }
  }
```

In above it is considered you have route `exceptions` defined in ember app.

Comment: Well, I have a jsp login page asking for a username and password... These details would go through a filter that throws user defined exception in some cases. So how do i make my exception class SEND that exception to ember?? How do i actually link my exception class to the ember page?

Comment: @User1337 This is not related to ember. You need to modify filters to send proper json payload when an exception occured. Please take look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782184/how-do-i-handle-error-states-in-servlet-filters-without-showing-the-user-a-stack

Comment: Are you saying its not possible?

Comment: @User1337 Of course there are some ways to achieve your goals. I just say sending exception from backend (filters) is a backend issue and not related to ember. Your exception payloads are just json object. You should define a general error (exception) data objects in backend and parse them in ember then decide to what to do in ember (like redirect to exception route)

Comment: Thank you,I'm kind of new to web app development and have very little idea about ember. It would be very helpful if you could just list the set of steps i should follow to send an error code in some way from my filter to ember. In simple words if possible. I just want ember to be notified that exception occurred.. the rest would be taken care by someone else.