# Does javax.servlet.error.exception attribute always cast to java.lang.Exception type?

Tags: java, servlets, exception, requestdispatcher

The attribute `javax.servlet.error.exception` in request with dispatcher type is `ERROR` can always cast to `java.lang.Exception` type?

I take a look at [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#ERROR_EXCEPTION), but it doesn't mention the type must be `java.lang.Exception` OR `java.lang.Throwable`.

I am asking this question because I am handling error page. If the attribute `javax.servlet.error.exception` always hold `Exception` type so I can write code as below without worrying about `ClassCastException` for all cases.

```
Exception exception = (Exception) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
```

Of course I can do like this:

```
Throwable error = (Throwable)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
```

but my handling is on `Exception` type ( Not `Throwable` ).

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. ERROR_EXCEPTION_TYPE at the link you provided is of type `String`.

Comment: Thank you! I typed wrong attribute name. I fixed it.

Comment: After your edit I still find the question somewhat misleading: "javax.servlet.error.exception" is the constant value of  `RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION`. But your main concern apparently is the behaviour of method `ServletRequest.getAttribute(String)`. And this is where `web.xml` and/or `ServletRequest.setAttribute(String, Object)` come into play.

Comment: @ Würgspaß: But servlet container do setAttribute automatically for exception information when the container does ERROR dispatch

Comment: Thats right. Anyway, there could be some call to `setAttribute` in the custom server code, as well. Or even someone is going to change the setting in `web.xml` in the future. So, I'd prepare my code for that to be on the safe side...    In any case, the issue is all about getAttribute/setAttribute, really. That was my point here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the `<exception-type>` associated with `<error-page>` entry in `web.xml` whose `<location>` refers the JSP/Servlet based resource in question.

If there's none, i.e. you're using a [general error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml/7066536#7066536) without any `<exception-type>`, or you're using only `<error-code>500</error-code>`, or you don't have any `<error-page>` at all, then assume `java.lang.Throwable`.

If there's an explicit `<exception-type>`, then assume exactly that type registered in `web.xml`.

Differently put, if you want to assume only `java.lang.Exception`, then set `<exception-type>` accordingly to that type.

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/your-error-resource</location>
</error-page>
```

Beware though that this way any `java.lang.Error` (i.e. matching `java.lang.Throwable`) will slip through and end up in server's default error page when you don't have an `<error-page>` for `500` or `java.lang.Throwable`.

#### See also:

- [Error Handler Servlet: how to get exception cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207586/error-handler-servlet-how-to-get-exception-cause/)
- [How can I print error stack trace in JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135980/how-can-i-print-error-stack-trace-in-jsp-page/32088347#32088347)

Answer (score 1):

> but my target is Exception

You can use `ERROR_EXCEPTION_TYPE` to find out the type and then retrieve the object using `ERROR_EXCEPTION`

```
String excType = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION_TYPE);
if ("java.lang.Exception".equals(excType)) {
   Exception exception = (Exception) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);
   //....
}
```

This could still raise a `ClassCastException`, however, if `ServletRequest.setAttribute()` was used in a mischievous way, for example.

If you care for other types as well, you could use a `switch` or reflection.